# Decomposition of representation that has multiple copies of isomorphic irreducible representations, of a finite group.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematical-physics

To better show where the weightlifting point is, I'll use $D_{3d}$ group as an example. The problem is that a 24 dimensional reducible representation of $D_{3d}$ is given, which is a matrix form $r_{\mu\nu}(g)$, $\mu, \nu = 1,\ldots, 24$. By canonical decomposition,  $r = 2 A_{1 g} \oplus 2 A_{2 g} \oplus 4 E_{g} \oplus A_{1 u} \oplus 3 A_{2 u} \oplus 4 E_{u}$. Here, $4 E_{u}$ means 4 copies of $E_u$ irreducible representations. The question is how to explicitly construct a decomposition of $4E_u$ into a direct sum of subrepresentations isomorphic to $E_u$. In other words, currently the basis of $4E_u$ representation is $(b_1, \ldots, b_8)$, under which the $4E_u$ representation is not $2\times2$ block diagonalized. How to obtain a set of basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_8)$ under which  $4E_u$ representation becomes $2\times2$ block diagonal?

In Serre's $\it Linear\ Representations\ of\ Finite\ Groups$, the following projector is given:
$$
p_{\alpha \beta}=\frac{n}{g} \sum_{t \in G} r_{\beta \alpha}\left(t^{-1}\right) \rho_{t}
$$
But here representation $r_{\beta\alpha}$ is already the irreducible representation, whose basis is unkonw yet. Therefore I don't know how to use this formula to tackle this problem.

The background is in the supplimentary material of paper "Two-phonon Absorption Spectra in the Layered Honeycomb Compound α-RuCl3", where the answer, the basis of the irreducible representation, is given. But I don't know how to obtain it or $E_g$ representations.

Does any one know how to tacle it?

---

Update:

I've now better understood the projector defined above. This projector is defined for arbitrary representations of G, thus can be used to decompose any representations. However, the remaining question is how to obtain $r_{\alpha\beta}(g)$, which is a known matrix form of an irreducible representation of G? Looks like chicken and eggs problem again.

Comment: I think that there are methods for solving this problem, which are (for example) available in Magma - I am not sure about GAP. I am afraid I don't know the details myself. The Magma expert on this topic is Allan Steel.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for such quick answer! Yes this should be a well solved problem. Maybe I could ask Allan Steel. I was just curious, that this problem is explicitly stated in Serre's book Linear Representations of Finite Groups section 2.7, and claimed to be solvable by projection operator. But I don't know how. Probably it's because I misunderstood the text somewhere.

Comment: The projection operator won't help you decompose an isotypic component (the sum of various copies of the same simple) any further. Just do something simpler: choose a non-zero vector in your isotypic component, and look at the vector space spanned by its images under the group action. That gives you one copy of the simple representation. Now choose another vector that is not in this copy and repeat until you have your direct sum decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that to use the Serre's formula shown above, at least one irreducible representation has to be known. And typically they are known. See the comments in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393186/decomposition-of-representation-that-has-multiple-copies-of-isomorphic-irreducib